# Python: problem during reverse array-- variable value changes without reassigning

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, variable-assignment, reverse

I have an array `A` `([1,2,3,4])` and want to define an array `B` with the first element the same as in `A`, while the rest are in the reversed order of the rest in `A`, ie. `B=[1,4,3,2]`. What I did was

```
A=[1,2,3,4]
B=A
C=A[1:4]
B[1:4]=C[::-1]
```

After executing this code, `A` became `[1,4,3,21`!! What's the problem here? How to keep the original array `A`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `B=A` creates another reference to exactly the same list, not a brand new list.

Comment: Try This: `B = [A[0]]+ A[1:][::-1]`

Comment: Thanks John and Rohit! I didn't know that it was totally different from Matlab:).  In my case array A is a column vector with the first element '0', by executing B = [A[0]]+ A[1:][::-1], I missed the first element in A (i.e. B became a column vector with one less element than A...). What's the proper way to treat column vector?